# Script keeps prompting me to insert disc into drive G:

Tags: file, batch-file, blackberry, delete-file

I have the following script which will delete a file off a BlackBerry.

However, every time I run it, it prompts me to insert a disc into drive G. Is it possible to rework it so it does not do that?

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
IF EXIST F:\home\user\videos\Star.avi (
ECHO "File Exists"
DEL F:\home\user\videos\Star.avi
) ELSE ( 
IF exist E:\home\user\videos\Star.avi (
    ECHO "File Exists"
    DEL E:\home\user\videos\Star.avi
) ELSE (
    IF EXIST G:\home\user\videos\Star.avi (
        ECHO "File Exists"
        DEL G:\home\user\videos\Star.avi
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO "File Doesn't Exist"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should only search and delete the file on the correct path/drive, not on F:, E: and also G:

Comment: How can I automatically obtain the drive that my blackberry is connected as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
SET DRIVE=
FOR %%D IN (E: F: G:) DO (
   IF EXIST %%D\home\user\videos\Star.avi (
      SET DRIVE=%%D
      GOTO EXIT
   )
)
:EXIT
IF DEFINED DRIVE (
   ECHO "File Exists"
   DEL %DRIVE%\home\user\videos\Star.avi
) ELSE (
   ECHO "File Doesn't Exist"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be something amiss with your paranthese pairs.  Why not simplify:

```
IF EXIST E:\home\user\videos\Star.avi (del E:\home\user\videos\Star.avi & goto exit)
IF EXIST F:\home\user\videos\Star.avi (del f:\home\user\videos\Star.avi & goto exit)
IF EXIST G:\home\user\videos\Star.avi (del g:\home\user\videos\Star.avi & goto exit)

:exit
```

Comment: Then why did you remove my award and give it to someone else?